# Streaming from memory mapped files in Qt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, memory-mapped-files

Is there any way to create a data stream that is located at the beginning of a memory mapped file in Qt?
Once i use `QFile::map` method, i get a `uchar*`. So is there any way to initialize a data stream with it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried it but there's a `QDataStream::readRawData()` function that accepts a `char *` and a length which you should be able to pipe that `uchar *` into. That'll give you your stream.