# C++ (Qt), System command using memory buffers instead of redirection

Tags: c++, qt, memorystream, buffering

I would like to know how to use memory buffers as the io streams to a system command using Qt.

Normally you would do something pseudocode like:

```
Exec Command(" command < inputfile > outputfile");
```

but I would like to do the entire operation in memory.

I would prefer Something psudocode like:

```
ByteArray input;
ByteArray output;
Exec Command("command name", &input, &output);
```

A specific reference, example or link to the answer would be awesome. I just need a starting spot, I think.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Removed the C tag because Qt is definitely not C.

Comment: This would be shell specific I'd think, e.g. Bash or Csh. Also, assuming `inputfile` has been recently written, and you read `outputfile` shortly after it is written, both should be in OS disk cache, so, effectively from memory. All that being said, ideally you'd avoid _shelling-out_ all together and find a library that can do the same as the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be to create memory-mapped input and output files, and specify full path to input and output files in regular shell command - this way it will effectively be in memory.

You can create/access those programmatically, take a look at

[Streaming from memory mapped files in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065879/streaming-from-memory-mapped-files-in-qt)

Answer (score 0):

I found out you can use a "shared memory" space and use it like a file reference. Once you have the file reference, you can use redirection with it. This is one solution anyway.